# Problems enqueuing javascript

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm absolutly new to wordpress theme development and I am having some issues
enqueuing my javascript file.

```
// Enqueue script
wp_enqueue_script( 'personaltheme-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/assets/js/bundle.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'personaltheme_script');
```

What am I doing wrong here? My styling seams to work so far:

```
function personaltheme_style(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'personaltheme-stylesheet', 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/assets/css/bundle.css', 
    array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_style', 'personaltheme_style');
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide errors or more details about what's going on when you run the code?

Comment: There is no error message provided by wordpress. I couldn't find the debug.log in wp-content.

Answer (score 0):

Try to register your script before:

```
function az_register_script(){
    // Register script
    wp_register_script('personaltheme-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/assets/css/bundle.css', 'array()', '1.0.0', true);
    // Enqueue script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'personaltheme-script' );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'az_register_script');
```

I Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Double check your stylesheet url. (Print the url and past it into your browser to check). And make sure your handle ('personaltheme-script') is unique. If another style uses the same handle your stylesheet doesn't get enqueued. Both cases fail without an error message

Comment: Oh and @David example is trying to enqueue a style as a script :p Change wp_register_script to wp_register_style and wp_enqueue_script to wp_enqueue_style

Comment: My stylesheet url is working fine as I sayed. I am only having problems loading my javascript filfe.

Comment: I noticed a mistake in my answer, I add your CSS, not the JS. Did you change it when you tried? Are you calling this function in your theme's file functions.php ?

Comment: Check the Path if it is correct, https://yoursite.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme/dist/assets/js/bundle.js . And try to change the name of the script: wp_register_script('personaltheme222-script',.....  and the same when you enqueue. The code is correct, I use it every day ;)